# Importing Geo Point (Lat, Lng) from MySQL into Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to import data from MySQL into an Elastic index using following Logstash script (ELK v 6.22):

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "E:\ELK 6.22\logstash-6.2.2\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fbk"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    statement => "SELECT fbk_repeat._URI AS URI, _SUBMISSION_DATE AS SUBMISSION_DATE, DEVICEID, LOCATION_LAT, LOCATION_LNG, SECTOR, COMMENTS, ACTION_TAKEN, PURPOSE
                    FROM
                    fbk_core
                    INNER JOIN fbk_repeat ON fbk_core._URI = fbk_repeat._PARENT_AURI"
  }
}



filter {

#    mutate { convert => {"LOCATION_LAT" => "float"} }
#    mutate { convert => {"LOCATION_LNG" => "float"} }
#    mutate { rename => {"LOCATION_LAT" => "[location][lat]"} }
#    mutate { rename => {"LOCATION_LNG" => "[location][lon]"} }

    mutate {
        # Location and lat/lon should be used as is, this is as per logstash documentation
        # Here we are tying to create a two-dimensional array in order to save data as per Logstash documentation

         add_field => { "[location][lat]" => [ "%{LOCATION_LAT}" ] }
         add_field => { "[location][lon]" => [ "%{LOCATION_LNG}" ] }
         convert => [ "[location]", "float" ]
    }


#    date {
#        locale => "eng"
#        match => ["_SUBMISSION_DATE", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
#        target => "SUBMISSION_DATE"
#           } 

}

output{
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
   index => "feedback"
   document_id => "%{URI}"
   document_type => "feedbackdata"
   manage_template => true

   # user => "elastic"
   # password => "changeme"


}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
   # stdout { codec => dots }
}
```

Once data is imported, I couldn't find any Geo Point field in Kibana to be able to plot data into a map, can anyone guide what must be going wrong.

Thanks!

**Data**
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to the index fields list (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.2/index-patterns.html#reload-fields). Also I don't understand what you are trying to do with `convert => [ "[location]", "float" ]`. I don't have any other idea, maybe you could add to your question some data sample and maybe the index mapping?

Comment: @baudsp added the data, can you guide about index mapping? I believe index mapping is automatically done by ES if one is not explicitly defined, please correct me if wrong

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-get-mapping.html#_multiple_indices_and_types to retrieve the mapping. The problem I was thinking about regarding index mapping is that the field `location` in the mapping got automatically assigned to another type that geo_point and since the mapping can't be changed, your problem is coming from there. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch can automatically do the mapping, but not for al fields.
You should set your mapping like this for example :

```
PUT index
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        },
        "field": {
          "properties": {
            "date": {
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
              "type": "date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adapt this to handle your data.

Don't forget to create the [index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-define-index.html) in Kibana.

Comment: Can you please list down the steps i.e. 1. Create index 2. Create complex mapping like Geo Point 3. ... ?

Comment: There is only one step, the precedent PUT will create the index with the given mapping. Just replace "index" and "type" with yours, and run this. If you give me an example of your data, I can try to give you the exact mapping. After that, you will only need to set the index pattern in Kibana.